# Understanding dimension of gradient flow trees for product on Morse complex

Tags: differential-topology, moduli-spaces, morse-theory

I am trying to square my intuition with the facts and hope this question is not too vague.

I am reading [this paper](http://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Efukaya/mfikki.pdf) which describes the $A_\infty$-category of Morse functions on a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, specifically the section on page 8 where they construct the moduli space $\mathcal{M}(p,q,r)$ used to define the product $C_*(f,g)\otimes C_*(g,h)\rightarrow C_*(f,h)$. I have a hard time understanding intuitively why the dimension of this space should be $\mu(p) + \mu(q) - \mu(r)$ ($\mu$ being the Morse index), as in lemma 1.7.

To me it seems that each such flow configuration corresponds to a point of intersection between the unstable manifold of $p$, the unstable manifold of $q$, and the stable manifold of $r$ (with respect to different Morse functions for each point of course).
The dimensions of these manifolds are $\mu(p)$, $\mu(q)$, and $n - \mu(r)$, so the dimension of the intersection ought to be $(\mu(p) + \mu(q) - n) + (n-\mu(r)) - n = \mu(p)+\mu(q)-\mu(r) - n$, generically.
So my intuition somehow wildly underestimates how common such flow configurations should be.
The case I picture is that of two index-1 points, whose gradient flow lines do not meet, generically, if $n > 2$.

My guess would be that I ether misunderstand something about the generic size of intersections, misunderstand something in the construction of the moduli space, or fail to take into account something about the relation between the Morse functions involved which makes this case less generic than if they were arbitrary.

Again I hope this sort of intuition-check question is not too vague.

Comment: I think your degree formula is correct and corresponds to the fact that the map in Prop 1.10 has degree -n. In particular Lemma 1.7 and Prop 1.10 do not seem compatible to me. The degree formula in Fukaya's paper suggests to me that he had in mind cohomological degrees, where one works instead with upward gradient flowlines of f, where all of this works out. The point is that if you apply PD three times to get a product on homology instead of cohomology, you get a degree shift in the product.